# Referencing a C# parameter name in an attribute, working on Windows, not on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, .net-6.0

I am having an issue when running a pipeline to build for a .Net 6 Web API project. I have code that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[MyAttribute(nameof(parameterName))]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromQuery] MyParameter parameterName)
{
    //Action logic
}
```

This compiles and works on my local machine (Windows 11 64 bit) in Visual Studio 2022 (17.7.6) but when I try to build a docker (via an AzureDevops pipeline) container to run tests against I get the following errors:

> /app/MyService/MyController.cs(xx, xx): error CS0103: The name
> 'parameterName' does not exist in the current context
> [/app/MyService/MyService.csproj]

The line referenced is `[MyAttribute(nameof(parameterName))]`.

I don't know if this is a Linux thing or an MSBuild thing or how to fix it. Our build agent is a Linux Azure VM (part of an Azure scale set). In the pipeline logs I see this:

> MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET

Comment: Maybe try updating MS Build ? I think that version is a year old

Comment: Actually - [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) say: _"Beginning with C# 11, you can use a `nameof` expression with a method parameter inside an attribute on a method"_ [C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11) is only supported on .NET 7.0.  Are you sure you are using .NET 6? Maybe your local machine is targeting 7.0 and your docker is targeting 6?

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I'm definitely targeting .Net 6 (`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`) but I do have .Net 7 on my machine and it wouldn't be part of the Docker image.

Comment: The way the error reads makes me think its probably not this, but the documentation states only C# 11 (thus .Net 7) has this feature, so you would at least think it wouldn't compile if it was using the wrong framework version

Comment: Think I may have found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version For example, building a project that targets .NET 6 from the current version of Visual Studio 2022 uses C# 10 if LangVersion isn't specified, but uses C# 11 if LangVersion is set to default.

Comment: Although I'm still unclear on how to fix the issue - other that use standard strings rather than `nameof`

Comment: A different docker image maybe? One that has .NET 7 instead?

Comment: You need .NET 7 installed to use C# 11. Visual Studio 2022 installs .NET 7. The version of C# and the version of the target framework are independent to an extent. Visual Studio is letting you target .NET 6 and use C# 11. For the Linux build, either back down to C# 10 or ensure that both .NET 6 and .NET 7 are available in the Linux image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to solve the issue by changing the Docker image I was using. I went from using:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
```

To using:

```
FROM alpine:3.18.5 AS base

FROM alpine:3.18.5 AS build
```

And adding the .Net packages I required:

```
RUN apk update && apk add dotnet7-sdk
RUN apk update && apk add dotnet6-sdk

RUN apk update && apk add dotnet6-runtime
```